# Inverse of Gamma Distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution

I am using python to calculate Inverse of a CDF of gamma distribution (using scipy. stat.gamma.fit). But for probability value 1, it is coming infinite. If it is replaced from 1 to 0.99 it works but the values changes with the different number of significant figures. Like it is 61 for 0.99 and 130 for 0.9999.

I do not know the best way to handle these infinite values in my workflow.I need to get a ideals but valid inverse value for probabilities arbitrarily close to 1. But i don't know, how to decide how many digits are needed to round off the probability value.  Also, I am not sure about, Will it be fine to round off?

Can we do something to get some meaningful information instead of inf value?

Thank you for your help

Comment: That sounds about right.  Why do you think there is a “situation” here?

Comment: I need to get the best possible inverse value near to 1. But i don't know, how to decide the upto which digit it is needed to round off the probability value.  Also, I am not sure about, Will it be fine to round off?

Comment: What does "best possible inverse value near to 1" mean? How near?

Comment: The correct value of the inverse CDF of all Gamma distributions at the argument $1$ is $+\infty.$ It sounds like your software is giving you the right answer.

Comment: yes..that is correct but @ReeBt well explained my problem

Answer (score 1):

Probability of 1 for an event means it will occur at every single possible instance. This means that in an infinite population an infinite number of events will occur. As @thelaconic suggests this is exactly what we expect.

I am guessing you need a solution that allows the algorithms to continue to provide meaningful results when applied. The best generic best solution is to detect inf (and >N) results and get your algorithm to insert N (number of instances) in the place of inf. That will allow you to apply the abstract inverse cdf to the actual dataset.

Comment: yes you are right.... i am looking for that only

Comment: In that case, if the answer has resolved your question please accept this as the answer or if not then indicate what further issues need addressed. Cheers.